# How to create a shortcut of data files that run through another program

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, shortcuts

I am trying to run a commandline-based emulator and I need to drag an `.iso` file onto the `.exe` so the `.exe` will run the `.iso`, or I have to open command prompt there and run it with commands.

I think the process could be reduced by creating a shortcut that runs the `.iso` data file via the `.exe` on Windows, but with barely any knowledge of the OS other than what could be done with the graphic interface, I have no idea how to set up the shortcut.

I know how to make a shortcut of `.exe` but I think I need some extra arguments for it to run the `.iso` ontop of that?

Comment: What kind of program (.exe) are you trying to use. Does it help file have something like 'prog.exe -i d:\test\myiso.iso'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragging a file onto an executable in Windows runs the executable with the full path to that file as the first argument. Therefore, you can create a shortcut with the following "Target":

```
"C:\path\to\executable.exe" "C:\path\to\file.iso"
```

and the following "Start in" path:

```
"C:\path\to"
```

[image: Shortcut tab in Properties dialog]

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want to know. Also on a side note, where do I get basic grasp of computer knowledge? Problems like this could be solved easily if i know how target field works and what arguments go there. I am starting to painfully recognise that I am seriously lacking basic computer knowlege for being born after that golden era of dos and rarely having a chance to fiddle with computers in youth. Is there something I can do to learn the basics, so it would help me with programming classes at uni.

Comment: @JacktheRipper Since that's such a broad topic range, there isn't one particular place to learn. In my case, I learned mostly just from being curious and trying things. You could also follow a few relevant Super User tags to see what questions and answers people post. Sometimes you can find some pretty interesting things that way.